# automatically change the hlines in RSI indicator depending on the trend

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to make the RSI indicator change vars on hlines automatically depending on the current trend. But I get this error

> Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='h'. An argument of 'series
> float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected

And I don't really get it how to workaround this error. Please help. Thank you. here's the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source")

var arrTrend = array.new_float()
var float trend = 0.0
h = input.float(0.0)
m = input.float(0.0)
l = input.float(0.0)

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)

rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
//
[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(1, 2)
array.push(arrTrend, direction)
//
if barstate.islast 
    trend := array.get(arrTrend, array.size(arrTrend) - 1)
    trendLabel = label.new(bar_index, high, trend > 0 ? 'down' : 'up' , yloc = yloc.belowbar, textcolor = color.white)

    if trend < 0 
        h := 80
        m := 60
        l := 40
    if trend > 0
        h := 60
        m := 40
        l := 20
        

band1 = hline(h, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(m, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(l, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)

fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hline` expects constant values. If you need variables to draw a horizontal line, use `line.new` instead.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2)
len = input.int(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source")

var arrTrend = array.new_float()
var float trend = 0.0
h = input.float(0.0)
m = input.float(0.0)
l = input.float(0.0)

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)

rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
//
[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(1, 2)
array.push(arrTrend, direction)
//
if barstate.islast 
    trend := array.get(arrTrend, array.size(arrTrend) - 1)
    //trendLabel = label.new(bar_index, high, trend > 0 ? 'down' : 'up' , yloc = yloc.belowbar, textcolor = color.white)

    if trend < 0 
        h := 80
        m := 60
        l := 40
    if trend > 0
        h := 60
        m := 40
        l := 20
    
    l_band1 = line.new(bar_index, h, bar_index+1, h, extend=extend.both, color=#787B86)
    l_bandm = line.new(bar_index, m, bar_index+1, m, extend=extend.both, color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
    l_band0 = line.new(bar_index, l, bar_index+1, l, extend=extend.both, color=#787B86)
    linefill.new(l_band1, l_band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90))
    
    line.delete(l_band1[1])
    line.delete(l_bandm[1])
    line.delete(l_band0[1])
```

Comment: wow cool thanks. But there is still a warning
'l_band1' is declared in local scope, which may not be executed at every update. So, obtaining its historical values may lead to unexpected results'

should I just ignore it? is it neccesarry to draw lines in the scope of the barstate.islast? thank you

Comment: No, you don't need to draw them there. You can draw them on the global scope.